# Probability, who is right?

Tags: probability, solution-verification, conditional-probability

A thief who is escaping has three paths to choose from A, B and C. Path B splits into 2 paths, BA leading to path A and BC leading to path C. In A he cannot escape, in C he escapes.
If it is known that the thief escaped, what is the probability that he used path BC?
I have a problem with this question, my friend say me this:

$\frac{(0.33*0.5)}{(0.33*1)+(0.33*0.5)}=0.33$

But i think that doesnt make any sence, i think that the answer is this

$\frac{0.5}{0.5+0.5}=0.5$

this is because we have the condition that the thief escaped, it can be assumed that he can only go by C or BC

Who is right?

Comment: The fact that there are only two winning choices does not mean that they are equally probable.  If you buy a lottery ticket, you either win or you don't...that does not mean that you have a $50\%$ chance of winning.

Comment: As an aside, $0.33\neq \frac{1}{3}$ so neither are right.  Don't use equals signs when things aren't equal but are merely *close*.  Use `\approx` instead.  $\approx 0.33$ is correct but $=\frac{1}{3}$ is more correct.

Comment: For intuition... imagine a similar problem.  A boy hopes to get a red jelly bean.  There are three bags.  In the first bag, it contains only two blue jelly beans and no others.  In the second bag, there are two jelly beans... one of which red and one blue.  In the last bag there are two red jelly beans.  Our boy picks a bag at random and then picks a jelly bean from that bag at random.  It should be clear that every specific bean in this scenario is equally likely to have been picked (*note the difference in the problem if bags had different quantities*)...

Comment: ... Of the three winning jelly beans, one of them came from the second bag.  That is in direct metaphor to your scenario of "given the thief escaped, what is the chance they started by going to B?"

Answer (score 4):

I think the following way helps to think about such problems.

Imagine there were 6 thieves. Two went to A, one to BA, one to BC, two to C. Out of this 3 survived, and from these three survivals there were just 1 who went through BC, so given that thief survived, probability of them going through BC is $1/3$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming selections of A , B , C is equally probable probability of doing so is $1/3 $
After choosing B again assuming splitting into BC , BA is equally likely probability of doing so is $1/2$ for each case .
Now probability of escaping is $$1/3 + (1/3)*(1/2) = 1/2 $$and probability of escaping by BC is $$(1/3)*(1/2) $$
Probability of using BC given that he has escaped is given by second answer divided by first answer because that is a conditional probability, so the answer is $1/3$.